# Label is not updating in Python Kivy, label "hello...." doesnt update to "listening....." on press

Tags: python, kivy

#label "hello...." doesnt update to "listening....." on press

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen

from kivymd.uix import screen

import pyttsx3

import datetime

import speech_recognition as sr

from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen

from kivymd.app import MDApp

from kivy.uix.image import Image

from kivymd.uix.button import MDFillRoundFlatIconButton, MDFillRoundFlatButton

from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField

from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel

from kivymd.uix.toolbar import MDToolbar


class JarvisApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        screen = MDScreen()
        #UI Widgets go here
        screen.add_widget(Image(source="logo.jpg",pos_hint={"center_x":0.5,"center_y":0.7}))

        self.label=MDLabel(text="hello.....",halign="center",pos_hint={"center_x":0.5,"center_y":0.35},theme_text_color="Primary",font_style="H5")
        screen.add_widget(self.label)

        screen.add_widget(MDFillRoundFlatButton(text="CALL",font_size=17,pos_hint={"center_x":0.5,"center_y":0.15},on_press=self.flipr))

        return screen
    def flipr(self,b):
        self.label.text="Listening....."
        r = sr.Recognizer()
        
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
          
            print(".....")
            r.pause_threshold = 1
            audio = r.listen(source)
            # 
        try:
            print("\n......Recognizing")
            query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')
            print(f"{query}")
        except Exception as e:
            print("\nSay that again please....")
            sys.exit()
        
        return query
    
  


if __name__ == '__main__':

    JarvisApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

The Label text is being changed, but the GUI isn't updated because you are holding the main thread with the `r.listen()` call. The Label cannot update until you release the main thread by returning from the `flipr()` method. Perhaps you can run the `r.listen()` in a different thread.